# JDK version error when building android app cordova

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3

Im trying to convert angular appliacation to an apk using cordova. When running

```
cordova build android
```

I get the following error

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/mohit/Android/Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/home/mohit/Android/Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 11.0.7
Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH environment variables.
```

Running command:

```
java --version 


openjdk 11.0.7 2020-04-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu218.04, mixed mode, sharing)

 sudo update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_version/bin/java
update-alternatives: error: alternative /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_version/bin/java for java not registered; not setting
```

Comment: You need JDK 8 not 11.

Comment: Can you help change the version.. Check my error?@andreszs

Comment: I did sudo update-alternatives --config java

Comment: update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in manual mode

Comment: but corona build showing same error @andreszs

Answer (score 1):

It's because you use OpenJDK where cordova requires Oracle JavaJDK. Version numbers do not match. Install Oracle JDK.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/mac_jdk.html

Comment: can you share the ubuntu link?

Comment: sudo apt install default-jre

default-jre is already the newest version (2:1.11-68ubuntu1~18.04.1).

Comment: is it a version issue . It showed detected version 11.0.7 . required 1.8?

Comment: Requirements check failed for JDK 8 ('1.8.*')! Detected version: 11.0.7 - can't be clearer than that